# How do i bind a button to close command in window style

Tags: .net, wpf, xaml

i want to create a custom close button in window style that it relyes window's close command.
i wrote something like this:

```
<Style x:Key="WindowsGeneralStyle"  TargetType="Window">
   ...
    <Setter Property="Template" >
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                <Grid>
                     ...
                     <Button x:Name="closebtn" Command={Binding Close} ... />
                </Grid> 
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

but it didn't work. How do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved problem. I create a partial class for our ResourceDictionary and in the behind code i handled Close button click event:

ResourceDictionary XAML file:

```
    <ResourceDictionary ...  x:Class="MyNameSpace.WindowStyle">
    ...
    <Style x:Key="WindowsGeneralStyle"  TargetType="Window">
            <Setter Property="Template" >
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Window}">
                        <Grid>
                             ...
                             <Button x:Name="closebtn"  Click="CloseBTN_Clicked" ... />
                        </Grid> 
                    </ControlTemplate>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
</ResourceDictionary>
```

and behind code:

```
namespace MyNameSpace
{
    public partial class WindowStyle
    {
        private void CloseBTN_Clicked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            Window.GetWindow(((FrameworkElement)e.Source)).Close();
        }
    }
}
```

Now,It works pretty well!

Answer (score 0):

`{Binding Close}` tries to bind to a `Close` command *in the current `DataContext`*, you probably want something like `{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Close}`.

Comment: Thank H.B. I changed it to "{x:Static ApplicationCommands.Close}" , now button appears disabled!

Comment: @AliAdl: From the docs: `There is not necessarily an implementation for the command on any given object; in many cases the implementation for the command is the responsibility of the application writer.` Usually it is quite useless, you will probably need to hook up the command to the `CanExecute` and `Executed` methods using a [`CommandBinding`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.input.commandbinding.aspx). Those methods then can implement the closing (and status whether the window can be closed, which affects whether the button is disabled or not)